# Finding which browser tab connects to a given IP address

Tags: linux, networking, google-chrome, firefox, browser

How can I find out which browser tab/task/webpage (Chrome foremost, Firefox second) is or has connected to a given IP address ?

For example, if I'm interested in one of SE's IP addresses, my system can tell me to which process an open connection belongs :

> user@host:~$ sudo netstat -ntp | grep '192.111'
>   tcp 0 0 192.168.92.2:35385 192.111.0.25:443 ESTABLISHED 4315/chrome
>   tcp 0 0 192.168.92.2:37311 192.111.0.25:443 ESTABLISHED 4315/chrome
>   tcp 0 0 192.168.92.2:36998 192.111.0.25:443 ESTABLISHED 4315/chrome

But within Chrome, which "page" is the connection associated with ? 
Ditto for Firefox.

Comment: did you try using the built in Web Developer tools (F12) to see the network traffic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a partial answer to your query.

Currently, you **cannot** do that with either Firefox or Chrome: there is a single process which takes care, simultaneously, of all pages.

I know nothing about future developments for Chrome (hence the `partial answer`, as I said above).

However, there is a project for Firefox to do exactly what you are asking. It is called *Multiprocess Firefox*, or *Electrolysis Firefox*, or *e10s Firefox* (these are all synonyms). You can find info on this project either [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Working_with_multiprocess_Firefox). In the first reference the developers state:

> The e10s team estimates e10s with a single content process will be enabled in Firefox Release by the end of 2015.

If you are truly anxious, you can install Firefox's Nightly builds and test e10s already, see instructions [here](http://arewee10syet.com/).